# How to show message in flutter after on Tap in google map "You are out of Zone"

Tags: flutter, google-maps

enter image description hereI have created a 430-radius circle on Google Maps.
I want one functionality when I click outside of the circle radius then the message shows you are out of the zone.

If I clicked within the circle then I want to show the message you are in your zone.

I have created a 430-radius circle on Google Maps and I compared the latitude and longitude of my current location.
In OnTap I have shown on e Toast message you are in your zone.
The problem is when I press out of the circle the message shows you are in your zone.
Same when I clicked within the circle same message showed.
I have used the if-else statement but I can't achieve the functionality which I want.

final List _list = [

```
Marker(
    markerId: MarkerId('1'),
    position: LatLng(25.00057631014206, 55.297173890099394),
    draggable: false, onDragEnd: (updatedLatLng) {
 // checkUp(updatedLatLng);

}),
//position: LatLng(latSelected, lngSelected),
```

];

Set circles = Set.from([
Circle(
circleId: CircleId('1'),
center: LatLng(25.00057631014206, 55.297173890099394),
radius: 700,
strokeWidth: 2,
// strokeColor: Color(0xFFB2DEFF),
fillColor: Color(0xFFE4F0F9).withOpacity(0.5))
]);

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Set<Circle> circles = Set.from([
    Circle(
        circleId: CircleId('1'),
        center: LatLng(25.00057631014206, 55.297173890099394),
        radius: 700,
        strokeWidth: 2,
        // strokeColor: Color(0xFFB2DEFF),
        fillColor: Color(0xFFE4F0F9).withOpacity(0.5))
  ]);

Answer (score 0):

There is a method `onTap(LatLng)` on google maps it will give you lattitude and longitude coords from parameters.

You can check from there whether the current coords are inside the circle or not.